# Parse data from SEMRush API in PHP [Semicolon separated]

Tags: php, arrays, csv, parsing

I do a Semrush API call and get the following server response:

```
Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA uniques;PLA keywords 
us;seobook.com;98072;14085;14300;62233;0;0;0;0;0
```

These are actually 2 lines where values correspond to each other. Example:

Database = us, Domain = seobook.com, Rank = 98072

and so on .. I need to parse these values into variables.

All I actually need is: `Domain, Organic Traffic, Organic Cost`

So i want to store their values into `$domain`, `$traffic`, `$cost`

How do I do this in PHP?

Please help anyone. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a format called CSV (character separated values). It is often used for large lists of records. PHP has a function `fgetcsv()` to read this format (from a file resource).

```
$csv = <<<'CSV'
Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost;PLA uniques;PLA keywords 
us;seobook.com;98072;14085;14300;62233;0;0;0;0;0
CSV;
$stream = fopen('data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($csv), 'rb');

$columns = NULL;
$values = [];
// read a line from the stream
while ($line = fgetcsv($stream, 0, ';')) {
  if (NULL === $columns) {
    // first line is columns, store it
    $columns = $line;
    // and continue with the next line
    continue;
  }
  // any other line combine the columns with the values and store
  $values[] = array_combine($columns, $line);
}

var_dump($values);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(2) "us"
    ["Domain"]=>
    string(11) "seobook.com"
    ["Rank"]=>
    string(5) "98072"
    ["Organic Keywords"]=>
    string(5) "14085"
    ["Organic Traffic"]=>
    string(5) "14300"
    ["Organic Cost"]=>
    string(5) "62233"
    ["Adwords Keywords"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Adwords Traffic"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Adwords Cost"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["PLA uniques"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["PLA keywords "]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

HINT: This example uses a data URL to access the CSV string as a file resource. In an actual implementation this not be needed, the API should provide a file resource/stream.